# MassTransit: Manual Ack and NoAck

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a understand problem; I have some clients listening on the same one queue, the message contains a client destination identifier, all client received this message but when this identifier is recognized by a specific one client, only in that case must be removed from the queue (ack), otherwise must remain (noack). I have try to generate a exception on ICosumer but it not work, I don't understand how work.

```
client = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AutoDelete = false;
    cfg.Durable = true;
    cfg.Exclusive = false;

    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri($"rabbitmq://{hostname}:{port}"), h =>
    {
        h.Username(username);
         h.Password(password);
    });

    cfg.Publish<MessageModel>(x => { x.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct; });

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, queueName, e =>
    {
        e.Consumer<MessageConsumer>();

     });
});

client.Start();
```

consumer:

```
internal class MessageConsumer : IConsumer<MessageModel>
{
    Task IConsumer<MessageModel>.Consume(ConsumeContext<MessageModel> context)
    {
        throw new MessageNotConfirmedException();
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if I write a possible duplication, but I don't found any solutions from many days.